# C# Abstract Class : Cannot implicitly convert type type1 to type2

Tags: c#, class, interface, abstract

I have an interface, 3 classes that implement the interface and one of these classes is supposedly abstract.

```
iAnimal // Interface
Animal // Abstract Class (Implements iAnimal)
Fox // Class (Implements iAnimal)
Deer // Class (Implements iAnimal)

Animal animal; // declare an animal
Switch (type)
{
     Case "Fox":
         animal = new Fox();
         break;
     Case "Deer":
         animal = new Deer();
         break;
}

animal.eat();
```

I only want to call the eat function on an animal which is the result of the switch statement.

However I get the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type type1 to type2.

Is there anything wrong with the above logic?

Thanks.

Comment: At what line do you get that error? What are the types of `type`, `type1` and `type2`?

Comment: Hmm, if you need `switch` statements like these, that generally means you are doing something wrong in your design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Fox` and `Deer` should inherit from `Animal` abstract class for your code to work.

ie:

```
public class Deer : Animal
{
     //code
}


public class Fox : Animal
{
     //code
}
```

Comment: Ah, they are implementing the interface, will change this and get back to you.

Comment: Then you can assign them to an `IAnimal` variable instead.

Comment: @CompuChip but then he would not need `Animal` class

Comment: Does it make sense to have an abstract class as well as an interface or just use the abstract class?

Its the first time I've done anything like this.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: It depends what do you need. Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d(v=vs.71).aspx for more guidelines

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of the following:

```
IAnimal animal; // Notice that it's an IAnimal now
Switch (type)
{
     Case "Fox":
         animal = new Fox();
         break;
     Case "Deer":
         animal = new Deer();
         break;
}

animal.eat();
```

OR

make the `Deer` and `Fox` class from the `Animal` class (in this case the code you posted will be the same)

EDIT:

Here's the class hierarchy as per the code you've posted

```
        IAnimal
           |
  -------------------
  |        |        |
Animal    Fox     Deer
```

You can cast an object of the derived type to a more generalized type (parent), so `Animal` -> `IAnimal`, `Fox` -> `IAnimal`, etc. is allowed
However it wont work with something like `Fox` -> `Animal`, because `Animal` is not a parent of Fox